# EmailService now has Twig render email messages in safe mode

Tags: emails

> EmailService now has Twig render email messages in safe mode.
>
> -- https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2903

I don't think this is really a bug as it's intended behaviour, but this is causing me a pretty big issue because my email layout has code in it like:

`{% set contactDetails = craft.globals.getSetByHandle('contactDetails') -%}`

But I think safe mode now means that the `craft` variable isn't actually available. I can pass it in manually when I'm sending non-standard emails with `craft()->emails->sendEmail()`, but has anyone found a way around this for the built-in ones like the activation/verification emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [Craft 2.6.2916](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2916), the email fields are no longer ran through Twig's safe mode.

> EmailService no longer has Twig render email messages in safe mode, which was a little heavy-handed and prevented email message templates from accessing global variables and other things.

Answer (score 4):

OK so it's pretty easy to pass additional variables to the email template using the [`email.onBeforeSendEmail`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#email-onBeforeSendEmail) event:

```
craft()->on('email.onBeforeSendEmail', function(Event $event)
{
    $event->params['variables']['craft'] = new CraftVariable();
});
```

Although I guess there are security reasons for email templates being rendered in safe mode in the first place so I don't know how much of a good idea this is...